# Implicit Differentiation (Textbook says ignore dy/dx)

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Find,

$$x^2y^2-2xy+x=2$$

find the slope and the equation of the tangent line at $(2,0)$ by implicit differentiation.

---

I have gotten this question wrong on a quiz and exam. I'm trying to understand it for my final. Part of the problem is that my text book says find $d/dx$ and then ignore $dy/dx$ after I get
$$x^2y^2=2x^2y$$

Please show me where I am going wrong. I would be able to find the equation of the tangent line if I had the correct $f '(x)$

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: (just for future reference, this isn't a "differential equation" so that tag isn't helpful)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing, but this is my take. Hope it helps.
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2y^2\right) - \frac{d}{dx}\left(2xy\right) + \frac{d}{dx}\left(x\right) = 0
$$
Then, remember that $\frac{d}{dx}\left(y^2\right)=\frac{d}{dy}\left(y^2\right)\frac{dy}{dx} = 2yy'$ (chain rule). Then, using product rule and chain rule, we have
$$
\left(2xy^2 + x^22yy'\right) - \left(2y + 2xy'\right) + 1 = 0 \implies y' = \frac{y-xy^2 + 1/2}{x^2y-x}
$$
Look over the Chain rule again, especially when you have $y$ in the expression you are differentiating.

Answer (score 0):

For your information, to ignore $dy/dx$ is a horrible advice.
Use a reliable textbook. You should be solving for $dy/dx$ instead.

[What you have to do is to bring terms containing $dy/dx$ on one side (say LHS) and other terms on the other side. Take $dy/dx$ as common factor on LHS. Divide the equation by what is remains other than $dy/dx$ on LHS]